# C function malloc() does not work as I expected

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I've been studying C language for several days and I'm currently making a simple console Contacts(address book) program to see what I've learned so far.
But in the process, I met this error and I don't know what I missed. 
Here's my code

```
int main() {
   startProgram();
}
```

This is my main function. It calls startProgram method, which calls printMenu function.

```
void printMenu(void) {
// print select page
   static Contact* contacts; // this value is for keeping Contact
                             // when the user inserted them.
   static int cnt = 0; // this is for counting the number of Contact.
   int choice;
   printf("%d\n", sizeof(contacts));  //prints 4
   if (cnt == 0) {
      init(contacts); 
   }
   printf("%d\n", sizeof(contacts)); // prints 4
```

I cut some other codes that are not related to this problem. Here's my problem. I wanted to initiate the variable contacts with the size of 5 elements.

```
void init(Contact* contacts) {
   contacts = (Contact*)malloc(sizeof(Contact) * 5);
   printf("%d\n", sizeof(Contact) * 5); //prints 200 (char[20] name + char[20] phoneNum)
   printf("%d\n", sizeof(contacts)); // prints 4 <-????????????
}
```

I expected the last one would be 1000 (it is 200 * 5) but what I got here is 4. The returned value from malloc() function is some memory address, not NULL. I've searched many articles but I couldn't find out what was wrong so far. Can you guys explain what I missed? Thank you for taking your time in reading this.

Comment: `contacts` is a pointer, and the size of this variable type is `4` on your system. The correct syntax is `printf("%zu\n", sizeof (contacts));` and the parentheses around `contacts` is unnecessary (only for a type). BTW the caller's  `contacts` will not be initialised – the pointer will not be passed back to the caller. All you get is a memory leak, and the caller's `static Contact* contacts; ` remains *uninitialised* except to a `NULL` value. Please take note of compiler warnings.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you for taking your precious time to help me on this. Then should I use & operator to pass the address of contacts for successful initialization? I didn't do it because I learned that array is a kind of pointer . and I can pass an array variable(not the address of the array variable) as an argument to change the value of array elements, which I guess I can pass a pointer variable(not the address) as an argument to change what it points to. I thought I understood the concept of pointer correctly, but I guess I'm totally wrong.

Comment: You are probably better off returning the pointer instead of passing it as a parameter, otherwise you would need to use a pointer-to-a-pointer.  So `contacts = init()`.  By the way, don't forget to `free(contacts)` when you are done.

Comment: Easiest is to return the pointer to allocated memory as the function value. But you don't even need a separate function – it's a one liner. `static Contact *contacts = malloc(sizeof *contacts * 5);`

Comment: @cdarke Thank you for your comment. I'll try that!

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you so much! I'll try that